# How to make table row wider on hover. (Angular, Typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I am trying to make table's row wider on hover than in it in the actual table, this is the code I have so far, I need to have result the same as on the first image, on the second image I have the current result, you can see that hover removes padding on the left and right part of the table so that the row takes the whole component.

I am working on Angular 13.

```
<div [ngClass]="!sharedEnum.paginationGroupIds.includes(taskGroupId) ? 'task_group_block' : 'task_group_block_pagination'">
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let header of currentTableHeaders">{{headerTitles[header]}}</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr [ngClass]="currentTableHeaders.includes('taskResultType') ? 'clickable_table_row' : ''"
          *ngFor="let item of tableData | paginate: { itemsPerPage: _itemsPerPage, currentPage: page }"
          (click)="industrialService.openTaskInsights(item)">
        <td *ngFor="let header of currentTableHeaders">
          <ng-container [ngSwitch]="header">
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'taskResultType'">
              <div class="task_group_types" style="white-space: nowrap" [ngClass]="'task_type_' + item?.taskResultTypeId">
                {{item[header]}}
              </div>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'title'">
              <div style="min-width: 350px">
                {{item[header]}}
              </div>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'authority'">
              <div style="min-width: 350px">
                {{item[header]}}
              </div>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'taskStatus'">
              <div class="task_group_types" style="white-space: nowrap" [ngClass]="'task_status_' + item?.taskStatusId">
                <img *ngIf="!item[header]; else statusType" src="assets/images/ui-kit-icons/icons/iconPlainLine.svg">
                <ng-template #statusType>{{item[header]}}</ng-template>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
              <div [innerHTML]="item[header]"></div>
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

````
table {
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;

  th {
    min-width: 120px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: var(--med-admin-white);
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    padding: 13px 10px 13px 10px;
    color: var(--med-admin-grey);
  }

  td {
    white-space: break-spaces;
    width: max-content;
    min-width: 120px;
    padding: 10px 10px 15px;
  }

  td {
    border-top: 0.5px solid var(--med-admin-light-grey);
    border-right: 1px solid var(--med-admin-light-grey);
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid var(--med-admin-light-grey);
  }

  th {
    border-top: 1px solid var(--med-admin-light-grey);
    border-right: 1px solid var(--med-admin-light-grey);
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--med-admin-light-grey);
  }

  th:first-of-type, td:first-of-type {
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  td:last-of-type, th:last-of-type {
    border-right: none;
  }

  .clickable_table_row:hover {
    background-color: var(--med-admin-hover);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}```

I am have tried to changes display: table-row to contents and work with it, but no result. Also tried to add separate directive displaying on hover, no result. Also tried to work with paddings and margins,but still didn't work. I am considering to change <table> and work with directive. Also considering using ag-grid if nothing else will work.
````

Answer (score 0):

Write `::after` for table row hover, Ex:

SCSS:

```
tr {
    position: relative;

    &:not(:first-child):hover{
        cursor: pointer;

        &::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            top: -1px;
            bottom: -1px;
            left: -5%;
            right: -5%;
            background: var(--med-admin-hover);
            border-top: 1px solid var(--med-admin-light-grey);
            border-bottom: 1px solid var(--med-admin-light-grey);
            z-index: -1;
        }
    }
}
```

It will gives you wider table hover, if you wanna fit it to table set
0 for left and right.